# create twitter like follow button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have been trying to create a twitter follow button. I followed some recommendations and the end result is not satisfactory. Last time it was working, and now I cannot put it to work besides all my efforts.

I would thought this would be more less simple and it has actually been a challenge!

Check code below (HTML, PHP, JS)

HTML

```
             <button class="btn btn-follow cenasparvas" id="<?php echo $profile_data['user_id']; ?>" type="button" onclick="status();"> Follow
```

JS (to actually update the database)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

function status() 
{

        var this = $('.btn-follow');
        var userid = $this.attr("id");
        var datastring = 'user_id=' + userid;
        if (!this.hasClass('follow')) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "follow.php",
            data: datastring,

                success: function(html)
                {
                    alert('sucess');

                } 
            });

        } else if (!this.hasClass('btn-danger')) {

            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "unfollow.php",
            data: datastring,

                success: function(html)
                {
                    alert('sucess aassss');


                } 
            });

        }

}
```

JS (the script that changes the type of button that appears - with support of bootstrap)

```
     <script type="text/javascript">

var btn = $('.btn-follow');

btn.click(h);
btn.hover(hin, hout);

function hin() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.text('Unfollow');
        btn.removeClass('btn-success');
        btn.addClass('btn-danger');
    } else {
        btn.addClass('btn-follow');
    }
}

function hout() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.text('Following');
        btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
        btn.addClass('btn-success follow');

    }  else {
        btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
    }
}

function h() {
    if (btn.hasClass('follow')) {
        btn.removeClass('btn-success follow');
        btn.text('Follow');
        btn.removeClass('btn-danger');
    } else {
        btn.text('Following');
        btn.addClass('btn-success follow');

    }
}
```

Comment: Your code seems OK. What is the problem? Any error on developer console on your web browser? Also, you didn't close `<button>` tag with `</button>`

Comment: Yes, I missed it, in the code I close it. I have no idea why it doesn't work!

Comment: Try in chrome/mozilla and press <kbd>F12</kbd> and select Console tab above. Add what you see there in your question.